# how to split json objects in to words in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

i am loading a dataframe of tweets in as JSON objects in pyspark.
I am trying to split the text in to individual words, and then select all the words that include a #. I want to try to avoid using regular python functions, adn try to stick with what is available inside of pyspark.

I am running the code as a jupyter notebook window: but this is the code overall.

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Jupyter Spark shell") \
        .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

folder = 'tweet-id-text-345'
tweets = spark.read.format("json").option("delimeter", "\t").load(folder)
tweets.count()
```

I am very unsure on how to do this. the viable result would be to get a sort of array of all the different words, and one for the different words that include a #. These would be two seperate lists.

Here is what the content looks like

```
+------------------------+
|                    text|
+------------------------+
|    โปรทุนน้อย สุดประ...|
|    RT @sOLehOXClj1XE...|
|RT @rkayama: 論文「関...|
| SixTONES OneSTのグッ...|
|    मुख्यमंत्री @mlkh...|
+------------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Comment: Can you show us what your original JSON looks like and the outcome? It's hard to help without a proper example

Comment: added what the content of the json looks like once it is spark.read on

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the json follows [this format](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/overview) the text of the tweet is stored in a field called `text`.

The text column is [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#split) into single words and the resulting array is [filtered](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#filter) using [rlike](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#rlike):

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
df=spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(<...>).select("text")
df.withColumn("all_words", f.split("text", " "))\
    .withColumn("only_hash", f.expr("filter(all_words, w -> rlike(w, '.*#.*'))")) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

If the original text was `hello #world how a#re you today#` the output would be

```
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
|text                            |all_words                              |only_hash             |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
|hello #world how a#re you today#|[hello, #world, how, a#re, you, today#]|[#world, a#re, today#]|
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: When i try to use your solution but switch out the names, i get an erro that says that "f is not defined" in the part where you do f.split.

Comment: I have added the required import `from pyspark.sql import functions as f`

Comment: Is there a way i can use that only hashdags column to get the count of the hastags in order of most common to least common?

Comment: Not really sure if I understand this follow-up question. Maybe you could create a new question and provide some example data?